# How can I reinstall gcc?

Tags: macos, xcode, development, gcc

Im new with mac and tried to install gcc / g++ on an MacBook Air with El Captain. I installed Xcode and used

```
xcode-select --install
```

It completed and was successful. However, for some reason I cannot find any version of gcc / g++ in /usr/bin or anywhere else besides the symlinks (cc c++ gcc g++) that point to nothing. I tried

```
gcc -v
```

and received the error

```
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

And when I try to reinstall the command line tools again with code-select I get

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Is there any way I can simply start over with the install of the command line developer tools?

Comment: How did you originally install gcc?  You could try again with Homebrew if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

Is Xcode installed in the normal location? (i.e. in /Applications?)

What do you get back from,

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
```

Can you see gcc at the following location,

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18560 16 Mar 00:31 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
```

If the path from xcode-select is not pointing to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer then try forcing to this location,

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```